# HABTM or HM/HMT Self-Join in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-many, self-join, has-and-belongs-to-many

I have a `Users` model and want users to be able to `Subscribe` to another `User` to get notifications when they post things.

This is sort of a has_many self join and a many_to_many self join.

I need to be able to type `@user.subscribers` and `@user.subscriptions`.

So, the relationship in one sense is both ways by default. However, if `@user1` `subscribes` to `@user2`, that does not mean `@user2` is `subscribed` to `@user1` howevver, `@user2` can find `@user1` via `@user.subscribers`.

I have seen Ryan Bates [Railscast on Self-Referential Associations](http://railscasts.com/episodes/163-self-referential-association). However that creates 1 way self-joins. But I think that doesn't leave the fact that there can be two relationships between the parties.

However, I have also seen [The Rails Guide on association foreign keys.](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has_and_belongs_to_many-association_foreign_key)

I realize I could probably the Ryan Bates way, and just build two relationships, but that seems wrong, but I fear that the second way won't allow one to be a subscriber and one to be a provider each way. What is the most "correct" way to go about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't over complicate things

```
class Subs < ActiveRecord::Base

    belongs_to :subscriber, :class_name => 'User'
    belongs_to :user

end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base

    has_many :subs
    has_many :subscribers, :through => :subs, :source => :subscriber
    has_many :subscriptions, :through => :subs, :source => :user
end
```

Obviously you have to set up the join model in your database. And that should do it.

Comment: I think this is right with the names reversed. I think the user is the subscriber and the result is the subscription, but it works. Thanks!